# Is there a proper way to write a program that runs continuously

Tags: c, linux, shell, cron

I want to continuously execute a C program on my computer. It doesn't actually have to "do" anything until it identifies an `event` though.

For example, the C program could be written with a `do while` loop that never exits. Inside the loop, there could be an `if else` condition that listens for an `event`. Lets say "`if` a file exists in a directory, then open the file and do something, `else` take a break and `sleep(60)` for a minute".

Of course this functionality can be implemented outside the C program. I could run the same idea above in the shell script..."`if` a file exists in a directory, then run C program, `else` take a break and `sleep(60)` for a minute". I could also write a shell script to execute the C program if a file exists and run the shell program with a `crontab` or some other scheduler.

If I didn't run `sleep` or I set the `crontab` to a very high frequency, then obviously my response time would improve. While that would be ideal, I have my doubts that is a safe and proper way to do this. I basically want my program to always be ready for action...an `event` occurs, get to work!

Since I've never implemented such a program, my question is, is there a proper and safe way of creating an "event-listener" that serves this type of functionality? C vs shell approach? Other ideas?

Comment: It depends on the event.  `man select`, and `man epoll`.

Comment: As for watching a directory in general, and not for the existence of a specific file, also see e.g. [`man inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html). Can be used to check if a specific files gets created in the directory though.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sticking with the context of my question, the event would be the "existence of a file". I'll check each of those though

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that inotify is Linux-specific, but the other major operating systems also have functionality like this.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It seems that the suggestions are to make use of existing Linux OS tools. I will add that tag as well in case someone has further input. I will check into your suggestion as well as the others above though. thanks

Comment: Have a look at how to daemonize a program, at how to start a daemon on system boot, and how to listen (asynchronously) for the kind of events you are interested in. Besides, your question is extremely broad and can not be reasonably answered in the scope of a single answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are actually want is to communicate between process.
using 'sleep()' and check a condition can be done but this is not the optimal way in terms of CPU consumption.

There for there several ways to communicate between processes, I know these:

1. pipe
2. shared memory
3. socket
4. Fifo

it is good to start pipe:
this can be use when you have 2 programs and you want program #1 to wait to some event from program #2.
I found an example [here](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/pipe.html) but there are many others in google.

after that I would continue with socket. one example is [here](http://www.programminglogic.com/example-of-client-server-program-in-c-using-sockets-and-tcp/) but again, there are many more in the web.

for further reading I can advice you to look for the book "Advanced Linux Programming" in chapter "Interprocess Communication".